# SignalR disconnects after 5 minutes in ionic app

Tags: asp.net-core, ionic-framework, signalr, ionic4

I'm using SingalR in ionic application with ForgroundService.
While the application is open signalr works without any error and after i lock the screen or close the app it keeps working for around 5 minutes, after that it stops working,
if i open the app after it disconnects it reconnects and gives me the error:

```
SignalR Disconnectundefined
SignalR DisconnectError: Error parsing handshake response: Error: Expected a handshake response from the server.
```

SignalR code:

```js
     public initiateConnection = () => {
        this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
          .withUrl(this.baseUrl + '/signalr-hubs/booking')
          .build();
        this.startConnection();
        this.onDisconnect();
      }
    
      private startConnection = () => { // Start connection 
    
        this.hubConnection
          .start()
          .then(() => {
            this.signalRConnectionStarted = true;
            console.log('Connection Started...');
            this.registerSignalEvents();
            this.getConnectionId();
            this.hubConnection.keepAliveIntervalInMilliseconds = 5000;
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err);
    
            setTimeout(function() {
              this.startConnection();
            }, 3000);
          }).catch(err => {
            console.log('Connection Timeout' + err);
          });
      }

      private registerSignalEvents() { // Event listener 
    
        this.hubConnection.on('DriverClientBookingUpdate', (order: OrderModel) => {
          this.orderSvc.handleOrderUpdate(order);
        });
      }

      public onDisconnect() { // I reconnect when signalR disconnects here
        this.hubConnection.onclose((err: Error) => {
          console.log('SignalR Disconnect' + err);
          this.startConnection();
        });
      }
```

foreground service in app copmonent

```js
    this.foregroundService.start(
      'Driver app is working',
      'Looking for potential orders ',
      '',
      1,
      10
    );
```

and the c# code that sends signalr

```cs
 await_hubContext.Clients.Group(_groupName).SendAsync("DriverClientBookingUpdate", bookingUpdateEto);
```

**Update**
after enabling logging
[image]

Comment: Edit your question and add a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I've updated the question with the code.

Comment: If possible, you can try to [enable logging in your SignalR app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-5.0), then check if there are any useful info about this error. Besides, you can try to comment out the code snippet `this.startConnection();` within the connection's `onclose` event handler, then check if that cause the issue.